# LWJGL's Display.create() is taking too long

Tags: performance, lwjgl

`Display.create()` used to be nearly instant, just like every YouTube tutorial depicts it. However, one day (sorry, I can't remember when) I began to get a white screen for 10 to 15 seconds before the program continued. This happened to every LWJGL project, even the ones that hadn't been modified since before the change. I know it's `Display.create()` because I added some extra lines of code around every init function.

The output was:

```
Initializing Display...
    Setting Display Mode...Done!
    Setting Window Title...Done!
    Creating Display...Done!
Done!
Initializing OpenGL...Done!
Creating Points...Done!
```

But every method except `Display.create()` went by so fast I couldn't see.

I've tried re-downloading a new version of LWJGL and even installing a fresh, bare-bones version of Eclipse. Minecraft still works perfectly despite relying on LWJGL. Is it possible that the workspace may have become corrupted?

**UPDATE:** When visiting relatives overseas, the startup time was quicker, but upon returning home it returned to the problematic state. What could be causing this?

Comment: try updating your graphics driver...and check whehther you are able to load other games that use LWJGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a quirk with eclipse; upon right clicking on the project and selecting `Go into`, the it ran more quickly. This may be because my workspace is to full.